# db<>fiddle (Oracle): Query works in 18c, but not 21c

Tags: oracle, spatial, oracle-18c, oracle-21c

I have a Oracle query that I use to analyze the vertices of SDO_GEOMETRY polylines:

```
WITH lines AS
 (SELECT SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY('MULTILINESTRING ((0 5 0, 10 10 10, 30 0 33.54),(50 10 33.54, 60 10 -10000))') tline
   FROM dual)
SELECT ct.id,ct.x, ct.y, ct.z as clcorr, vt.z as clorig
 FROM lines,
 TABLE(sdo_util.getvertices(SDO_LRS.CONVERT_TO_LRS_GEOM(SDO_CS.make_2d(tline)))) ct
 JOIN table(sdo_util.getvertices(tline)) vt
   ON ct.id=vt.id;
```

Source: [Find polyline vertices where M-value is not cumulative length](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4497001/find-polyline-vertices-where-m-value-is-not-cumulative-length)

---

That query works in db<>fiddle for Oracle **18c**:

- [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPLGM.png)
- [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6afc20f0c18d8f740cb711d8eb0cc9f1)

But the same query produces an error in db<>fiddle for Oracle **21c**:

```
ORA-00904: "CT"."Z": invalid identifier
```

- [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSdyh.png)
- [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6afc20f0c18d8f740cb711d8eb0cc9f1)

---

Why doesn't the query work in db<>fiddle for Oracle 21c?

Comment: It's not related to dbFiddle - it just doesn't work in 21c

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Thanks. For what it’s worth, the query works in 19c too (tested in https://livesql.oracle.com/, which is 19c). Do you mind me asking what versions you tested in? Were they local versions?

Comment: Tested in 21.2.0.0.0 (Free Oracle Cloud) and 19.3.0.0.0. In my 21c database, `select sdo_util.from_wktgeometry('MULTILINESTRING ((0 5 0, 10 10 10, 30 0 33.54),(50 10 33.54, 60 10 -10000))') tline
from dual` fails with *ORA-13199: JavaVM or SDO Java Stored Procedures not installed* starting at MDSYS.SDO_UTIL, though it seems OK in DBFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

sdo_util.from_wktgeometry is not yet supported on Oracle Autonomous Database on shared infrastructure (ADW, ATP-S). It currently requires Java in the database which is restricted as listed at https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/unavailable-oracle-database-features.html. The Spatial doc includes a note under Usage Notes for operations that have this limitation, for example https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/spatl/SDO_UTIL-reference.html#GUID-EFDD565A-E565-4463-9CFC-464DC856ECB7. This limitation is being addressed.

Comment: Thanks! Question: This works ok in Oracle 21c db<>fiddle: `select sdo_util.from_wktgeometry('MULTILINESTRING ((0 5 0, 10 10 10, 30 0 33.54),(50 10 33.54, 60 10 -10000))') tline from dual`. I wonder why the full/original query doesn't work in 21c db<>fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the follow-up question, the issue appears to be with the JOIN operator. This works in 21c db<>fiddle:

```
WITH lines AS
 (SELECT SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY('MULTILINESTRING ((0 5 0, 10 10 10, 30 0 33.54),(50 10 33.54, 60 10 -10000))') tline
   FROM dual)
 SELECT  ct.id,ct.x, ct.y, ct.z as clcorr, vt.z as clorig
 FROM lines,
  TABLE(sdo_util.getvertices(SDO_LRS.CONVERT_TO_LRS_GEOM(SDO_CS.make_2d(tline)))) ct,
  TABLE(sdo_util.getvertices(tline)) vt
 WHERE ct.id=vt.id;
```

Comment: Good catch! I wonder what the explanation is. Did Oracle stop supporting the JOIN syntax in certain scenarios?